# Maven Plugin - How to use resources from a project within a custom plugin?

Tags: sql, maven, resources, maven-plugin

I am in the process of designing a maven plugin that will pick up on a set of sql scripts contained within src/main/resources of a given project and then running them as part of a maven build.
Was just wondering if there is a standard way of using project resources within maven plugins or whether there is any examples that I can take a look at? I assume other plugins such as the maven-javadoc-plugin do something similar but I am not sure where to look

Comment: Do you know http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/ ?

Comment: I do not. I will take a look through the documentation.